# Getting select value from select list and concatenating it to Post action from my form

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

My idea is posting to an URL (kind of like a rest service) and it will receive 2 parameters (id and type), like this: `http://localhost/thing/save?id=objectReceivedFromSpringAttributes.id&type=selectedOption"`

This `selectedOption` has to be the option selected from the dropdown list:

```
<form id="docForm" class="container-fluid" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"
    th:action="@{'/thing/save?' + 'id=' + ${objectReceivedFromSpringAttributes.id} + '&type=selectedOption'}">
    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <label>Tipo</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <th:block th:each="type : ${docTypes}">
                        <option th:text="${type.typeText}"></option>
                    </th:block>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer" > 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal" th:value="#{nuevasolicitud.versolicitud.cerrar}">Cerrar</button>
        <input id="saveDoc" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" th:value="#{nuevasolicitud.versolicitud.enviar}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the select value by adding a name to the select tag (for example: `name="selectTag"`) and then add the following as a method argument to the correct method in your controller:

`@RequestParam("selectTag") String option`

Now you can acces the selected option in your controller method as "option".

(like so: `String thisIsTheOption = option`)

I'm not sure how to instantly concatenate it to the URL though. 
It's a POST though, so do you really need these things in your URL instead of request body?